# How to enable a particular sub-menu in Rshiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am developing a shinyApp using a dashboard package. In that a menu item has 2 sub-menus and the application has to react according to the selection of the sub-menu. But without selecting the sub-menu I have my data displayed. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?
This is the code snippet used. Thanks in advance.

```
dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
       menuItem('Modify',
                menuSubItem('Edit details', tabName = 'edit'),
                    )
      )),

    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = 'edit', 
                hotable('hotable1'),
                downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
        )
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I completely understand your question but from what I gather you are questioning why the table appears on application initialization without the user clicking the `menuSubItem`. This is the default behavior in Shiny Dashboard, the app will start with the first `menuSubItem` as the default value, if you desire a particular `menuSubItem` as the starting sub-tab that can be achieved using the `selected` option under `menuItem`

Here is a reproducible example exhibiting the same behavior, in order to explicitly highlight this behavior I've used `startExpanded = TRUE`. Here you can observe the first subMenuItem is selected by default. More on childfull menuItem() can be referred [here](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/behavior.html#know-which-menuitem-if-any-is-currently-expanded)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(), 
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Modify",startExpanded = TRUE,
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 1", tabName = "subitem1"),
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 2", tabName = "subitem2")
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("subitem1", "Sub-item 1 tab content"),
      tabItem("subitem2", "Sub-item 2 tab content") 
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```